# Can't get configuration profile of AppConfig from AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-ssm, aws-app-config

**Lambda function - Node.js**

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  var appconfig = new AWS.AppConfig({ apiVersion: '2019-10-09' })
  var params = {
    ApplicationId: '6xeris1',
    ConfigurationProfileId: '0ck2ijf'
  }
  const data = await appconfig.getConfigurationProfile(params).promise().catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })

  if (data) {
    console.log(data)

    const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST,GET'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }
    return response
  } else {
    const response = {
      statusCode: 500,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST,GET'
      },
      body: {}
    }
    return response
  }
}
```

When `getConfigurationProfile` is called there is no response. No data, no error and the function get timeout.

I added below inline policy to Lambda execution IAM role, but it didn't work.

```
"Action": "appconfig:*"
```

Anyone solved this issue before me? Thank you.

Comment: Is your function in a VPC?

Comment: Yes. I removed VPC connection, and it works. Thank you.
But I am going to connect RDS so VPC may be required. In this case, should I open 443 of the RDS security group?

Comment: Glad to hear. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was due to the fact that lambda function was configure to be **in a VPC**. However, functions in VPC don't have internet access nor public IP. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html):

> Connecting a function to a public subnet **doesn't give it internet access or a public IP address**.

The **solution** was to use [VPC endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html).

Comment: Thank you. The lambda function should be in VPC to connect RDS, and VPC endpoint was useful. But your comment helped me solve this issue faster. Thanks.

Comment: @Kim-Jimin Thanks for letting me know. I will add vpc endpoint to the answer.